# What is the legality in the UK of a minor transporting alchohol?

Tags: united-kingdom, minor, alcohol

We are discussing in work a colleague who will be 18 in February, the work just gave alcohol to all Adult staff and so it was asked, could colleague A (who is 17) transport the alcohol he could have been given, home, to deliver to his parents?

A short google brings this interesting tidbit
It is only illegal for persons under the age of 18 to consume alcohol in a public place according to the Children and Young Persons Act 1933
Source(s): Legislation.gov.uk

but you know how unreliable people on the web can be with the actual law.

Answer (score 1):

Though the act does not directly address the issue of donating alcohol, it is likely that under [section 151 of the Licensing Act 2003](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/17/section/151) it would be considered an offence to provide (free of charge) alcohol to a minor, considering the purpose of the provision.

> (1)A person who works on relevant premises in any capacity, whether paid or
>   unpaid, commits an offence if he knowingly delivers to an individual aged 
>   under 18—
>
> (a)alcohol sold on the premises

Comment: "relevant premises" would this not be any premises which provides/sells alcohol?

Comment: In relation to the act, I agree that it would make sense that 'relevant premises' were those licensed to sell alcohol.